# I have a small 196cc 6.5 horse power engine

Tags: small-engine

I am using this motor in a small pit bike. And was wondering why there was 2 oil spots. I was told on is for the motor oil and one is a white merky fluid but dont know what to look for. Please help.

Comment: Can you add some more detail or add some images, that would help?

Comment: Agree with @Dan - Pictures are worth a thousand words. Also, what *make* is the engine?

Comment: It's a power fist. The model number is 8088378. And I can add any pictures. But it has 2 yellow oil plugs on opposite sides of the motor.

Comment: Can't add any pictures***

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you with certainty that there is no white merky fluid that ever goes into a motor. Usually merky white fluid is a sign of condensation mixed in with engine oil. As far as two yellow plugs I'm only seeing one on my google image search which is your engine oil fill plug

Comment: hold on I may have found what you are looking at. is this what you see?
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/OwshTzB3Roo/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: I have an older motor. And there are 2 yellow plugs that say oil. And I don't know if they go to the same place or not.

Comment: http://images.palcdn.com/documents/showcase/project_20/snowblower-engine-swap-02.jpg It has the one oil cap on the right. Then myn also has one on the left of the shaft. In starting to think it just has 2 spots to put engine oil

Comment: I agree with Josh both of those plugs go to the crankcase. Probably designed that way so that no matter that they go in there was an easy access to fill it with oil

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Glad that we figured it out.